# I want to remove a wall dividing my living room from my porch

Tags: beam

The ceiling joist on the porch runs east and west connecting to the last ceiling joist over the living room, which runs north and south.  The roof is a hip roof and has no load on the ceiling.

The ceiling consists of 2x8x12 overlapping each other in the center,  1/2" drywall and 8" of insulation. Currently  the living room is supported by two 2x6x12 (*10 foot visible*)  with 1/2" OSB in between.  I need to span a total of 16 feet with a 1 foot overhang on each end.

Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Please **clarify your question.** The only *question* here is *"suggestions?"* which is excessively vague for the format of this site.

Comment: Also removing an exterior wall requires way way more input than knowing the roof type or where the header is.   Quite frankly you are really wasting your time here as this is such a risky question to ask you will have to basically give a mountain of information and the answer will still be, consult an engineer.   Even if someone gives you good advice there is no way your city will let you do it without plans from an engineer.   This is an outside wall - vertical load isn't your only concern.

Comment: Is the porch original to the house?

Comment: @DMoore That  is an answer, and a correct "**suggestion**". ;) , in fact it is a more verbose  version of my answer. My answer is a comment and your comment is an answer, They both say,  you need an engineer.

Comment: The question should be closed as too broad. There are no suitable answers.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated the wall is an interior wall leading to an enclosed front porch.    I stripped the wood off of the porch side of the wall and the 2x4's that is the wall I want to remove DO NOT feel as though they are under load.  would be easier if the ceiling joists all ran the same way but since they don't I'm asking

Comment: Does the porch have shear walls or just windows all around? Are you in a seismic zone or high wind area? Is the final “open” area that the beam has to span is 16’? What is the depth of the porch that rests on the new beam? Can you answer Jim Stewart’s question?

Comment: ok so th posch is native to the house.  the basement runs underneath it.  the exterior walls of the porch area are structurally sound.  the only addition would be to add a header to help support the beam better.the pocket for the beam is 4" .

Answer (score 6):

You want to remove an exterior wall that is integral to the structure of the building so you will need to know how to provide a suitable, to code, way to support the load that the wall is carrying.

**Suggestion:**   Hire a Structural Engineer to tell you what is required.

You will need a structural engineer to **size the correct beam and post system** that will be needed to replace the wall.

Comment: thats a comment

Comment: No,  it is an answer to the question "suggestions"

Comment: then every electrical question can be, hire an electrician...

Comment: I want to fix this shelf, hire a carpenter

Comment: @DMoore. Not every electrical problem needs a licensed electrician to remedy it. Every load bearing wall removal **does require a properly engineered solution**. It is the proper answer, regardless of your approval. Take deep breath, everything will be OK.

Comment: I am not trying to argue with you - you give good answers.   But this is a comment.   We probably have 50+ load bearing questions on here with good answers that do not need an engineer.   Just saying.